# Just need to know how to get the numbers from an array and add it up. NB. The number will be given by the user .

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class Revision {

static int[] num = new int[3];
static int i ;
static int sum;

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    System.out.print("Enter the 4 numbers");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    sum=sc.nextInt();   
    for(i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
            sum=sum + num[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Sum=" + sum);
}
```

Comment: get the numbers from user or array or both?

Comment: When did you put the numbers in array? Before using it in the for-loop?

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. Simply posting code and expecting people to answer your question is rude!

Comment: I cannot find a question in this post. What is your question and what's the problem with the above code (besides the fact that there a too many curly brackets)?

Comment: I agree with @bot. We're no answering machines.

Comment: Question is specified in the title, "Just need to know how to get the numbers from an array and add it up. NB. The number will be given by the user .". He is just joined. Please don't fire on him :)..Give him a chance atleast to correct it, before down voting..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Revision {

static int NO_LIMIT = 4;
static int[] num = new int[NO_LIMIT];
static int i ;
static int sum;

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while(count < NO_LIMIT){
        System.out.print("Enter the number" + (count+1) +":");
        num[count] = sc.nextInt();
        count ++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
            sum=sum + num[i];
        }

    System.out.print("Sum=" + sum);
}

}
```